# Ist doch deide!

Tags: expression, dialect

> "Ist doch deide!", sagte Kali und klang ehrlich begeistert. (Theresa Hannig, *Die Optimierer*, 2017)

I cannot find anywhere the word *"deide"* is it some dialect?

What does "Ist doch *deide*" mean?

Comment: Where did you find that sentence?

Comment: @David Vogt _Die Optimierer_
Theresa Hannig · 2017

Comment: In one book: Die Optimierer from Theresa Hannig

Comment: @choXer Die ngrams sind teils so schrottig! Dort wird ganz häufig aus "cleide" (="Kleide" als Dativ von "Kleid") "deide" und aus "cleider" (="Kleider") "deider". Anstatt "Gott" kommt auch schon mal "Bott" heraus, weil die Google-Tools offenbar ein Problem mit gebrochenen Schriften (insbesondere im Zusammenhang mit unkonventioneller Rechtschreibung) haben - hier würde ich zu großer Vorsicht raten.

Comment: @Wolf Wow, du warst ja schnell. Ich hatte eben mal nachgeschaut und bin zu dem selben Schluss gelangt, danke :)

Comment: Aber ich war auch irgendwie langsam: erst zum Schluss bin ich im richtigen Zeitalter gelandet und habe das Buch gefunden ... und mich dann schon in der Vorschau festgelesen :) [&quot;ist doch deide&quot; - Google Suche](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ist+doch+deide%22&lr=lang_de&tbs=lr:lang_1de,cdr:1,cd_min:2000,cd_max:2099&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk03pMqQd1u40Sx-DzSJKbb3V75qH5Q:1608155357062&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOhbTGvdPtAhWIzaQKHbbLBw0QpwUIJQ&biw=1920&bih=919&dpr=1)

Comment: Es würde auch helfen zu erwähnen, ob sonst im Buch Dialekt vorkommt, oder Szenejargon. Wolfs Link zeigt mir nur wenige Zeilen Text ohne Dialekt. Allerdings stolperte ich dort über das Wort "Piretist" was mich fragen lässt, ob es ein Musikinstrument gibt, das ich noch nicht kenne. Spielt offenbar in der Zukunft, 2050 etwa, also womöglich eine phantasievoll antizipierte Sprachentwicklung.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Zitat aus einer [Rezension](https://www.buchensemble.de/die-optimierer/) von Kia Kahawa:

> Samson Freitag ist ein Lebensberater in “die Optimierer”. Die Geschichte spielt im viel zu heißen Spätsommer 2052, Samson ist wohnhaft in München, BEU. Die BEU ist die Bundesrepublik Europa, die sich vom Rest der Welt abgeschottet hat.

> ...

> Das findet Frau Fischer ganz und gar nicht deide.

Zu dem mysteriösen "deide" (das an zehn Stellen des Buchs vorkommt) gibt es die Fußnote

> Deide ist ein Wort, das im Jahr 2052 als Ausdruck für “cool”, “nice” oder ähnliche Wörter verwendet wird.

Es dürfte sich also um eine Erfindung der Autorin handeln.

Comment: Short answer: it's a made-up sci-fi word, like 'Jedi'.

Comment: https://www.thisworddoesnotexist.com/

Comment: There is no footnote in the book, they forgot it or it was done on purpose.

Comment: @onetwo12 The footnote occurs in the review of the book (see the link). The word "deide" is certainly a creation of Theresa Hannig and the ten occurrences in the book lead to the conclusion that it means something like *cool*, *nice* etc.

Comment: Yes I saw that thanks, but it would have been nice to be in the book also.

Comment: @onetwo12 I didn't read the book, but I saw all ten occurrences of "deide" (via Amazon preview): There is no explicit explanation by Theresa Hannig.